# What will be the best possible way to simulate the touch on the display screen?(without robot)

Tags: xamarin.ios, touch, microcontroller, robotics, cartesian-coordinates

Recently I have been assigned to develope a system that simulates a series of mechanical touch on the display screen, I have suggested **ARM robot as well as Cartesian coordinate robot**, but both were rejected due to safety issues, My superiors are expecting a fast, reliable non-robotic mechanical setup that can triger the touch screen(Mechanically).

'The display is a normal Capacitative touch dispaly'

Thanks a lot for your valuable time

Comment: So you're looking for a mechanical automation that isn't a 'robot'.  I'm not sure this is a question for stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question really doesn't belong on this forum, here are two possible solutions.

1. Depending on the requirements of the project, you could assemble an array of solenoids to be placed over the screen.  Each solenoid would have a mechanical "rubber finger" attached to its plunger. The rubber fingers would need to be made of a conductive rubber material that is electrically connected to ground. Activating a solenoid would extend the plunger to touch the screen.
2. Eliminate the solenoids, and just have an array of conductive rubber fingers, which are all touching the screen simultaneously. Each rubber finger is connected to an open-drain driver circuit that, when activated, connects the finger to ground, thus creating a "touch." When de-activated, the rubber finger needs to electrically "float".